# Update jQuery Invoice Total on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a query invoice which only updates the total values when a field is altered. As I am generating the invoice items using PHP I really need the values to update as soon as the HTML is generated.

How can I call the update_total function the moment the document has finished rendering?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will run the update_total function as soon as the page has completely loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    update_total();
});
```

You can read more on the .ready method here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Ahh it was staring me in the face the whole time! Thanks!